# cocoa: how to render view to image?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to know is there any method to render a view to image? just like a screenshot, but I can specify any view to that method. I know how to do it in ios. [Saving view content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213529/saving-uiview-contents-in-ios-4-with-real-size-of-the-images-inside-i-e-scale), but how can I do it in mac os ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several ways, but non of them works perfect.
Many problems are connected with Layer Backed views.

if you don't have layer backing or hosting views you can use this code:

```
    NSData* data = [mainView dataWithPDFInsideRect:[mainView bounds]];
    NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

if you work with layer based views:

till 10.8 the best way for me was

```
        NSSize mySize = mapImage.bounds.size;
        NSSize imgSize = NSMakeSize( mySize.width, mySize.height );
        NSBitmapImageRep *bir = [mapImage bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[mapImage bounds]];
        [bir setSize:imgSize];
        [mapImage cacheDisplayInRect:[mapImage bounds] toBitmapImageRep:bir];
        caheImg = [[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:imgSize];
        [caheImg addRepresentation:bir];
```

but in 10.8 `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect` stopped working with Layer Backed views.

there is an option to make a screenshot of your screen and cut out your view:

```
+ (NSImage*) screenCacheImageForView:(NSView*)aView
{
    NSRect originRect = [aView convertRect:[aView bounds] toView:[[aView window] contentView]];

    NSRect rect = originRect;
    rect.origin.y = 0;
    rect.origin.x += [aView window].frame.origin.x;
    rect.origin.y += [[aView window] screen].frame.size.height - [aView window].frame.origin.y - [aView window].frame.size.height;
    rect.origin.y += [aView window].frame.size.height - originRect.origin.y - originRect.size.height;

    CGImageRef cgimg = CGWindowListCreateImage(rect,
                                           kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow,
                                           (CGWindowID)[[aView window] windowNumber],
                                           kCGWindowImageDefault);
    return [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimg size:[aView bounds].size];
}
```

Comment: Your version with bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect works fine for me on 10.7 for a layer backed view and I added your screenCacheImageForView for 10.8 - upgraded since some days to 10.8.3, but screenCacheImageForView causes problems with my view (which has 2 additional NSTextField labels on top and errornously included in the view's screen shot). But: on 10.8.3 the bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect works fine - didn't it before 10.8.3?

Comment: Maybe apple has fixed the issue 10.8.3, i was writing the code when there was only 10.8.1. But your app users can still have older os version, so it is better not to use this method in 10.8

Comment: Apple's 10.9 release notes claim to have fixed the problem with cacheDisplayInRect and layer backed views.  However note that in some circumstances I have found the problem remains in 10.10.  However, dataWithPDFInsideRect appears to work fine with layer backed views, and produces resolution independent images which are much smaller, so may well be a better solution now.

Comment: I'm running 10.10.5. dataWithPDFInsideRect gives me the following error: Assertion failed: (s->stack->next != NULL), function CGGStackRestore, file Context/CGGStack.c, line 77. However bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Remizorr works in ObjectiveC like explained even under 
macOS High Sierra 10.13.4. - Xcode 9.2.

It also works for layerBacked view (`wantsLayer = true`).

Here is the updated Swift version :

```
extension NSView {

func snapshotImage() -> NSImage? {

    guard let window = window,
        let screen = window.screen,
        let contentView = window.contentView else { return nil }

    let originRect = self.convert(self.bounds, to:contentView)
    var rect = originRect
    rect.origin.x += window.frame.origin.x
    rect.origin.y = 0
    rect.origin.y += screen.frame.size.height - window.frame.origin.y - window.frame.size.height
    rect.origin.y += window.frame.size.height - originRect.origin.y - originRect.size.height
    guard window.windowNumber > 0 else { return nil }
    guard let cgImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(rect, .optionIncludingWindow, CGWindowID(window.windowNumber), CGWindowImageOption.bestResolution) else { return nil }

    return NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: self.bounds.size)
}

}
```

NOTE: This works even for a WKWebView and it does take a snapshot of a WKWebView video playing (which WKWebViews takeSnapshot does not) ;).

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe it took me hours to find this!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code in my app, which works great.

However, if I drag the app to a secondary monitor the screen capture is thrown out and I get the wrong rect captured.

The following code fixes that issue (I've also removed some redundant maths from the calculation where a field was being subtracted and then added) in case anyone comes across this in the future:

```
NSRect originRect = [aView convertRect:[aView bounds] toView:[[aView window] contentView]];

NSArray *screens = [NSScreen screens];
NSScreen *primaryScreen = [screens objectAtIndex:0];

NSRect rect = originRect;
rect.origin.y = 0;
rect.origin.x += [aView window].frame.origin.x;
rect.origin.y = primaryScreen.frame.size.height - [aView window].frame.origin.y - originRect.origin.y - originRect.size.height;
```