# WebView to TIFF representation

Tags: image, macos, cocoa, webview

I'm trying to capture the contents of a `WebView` and saving it as an image. This is my code right now (`cv` is the web view):

```
[cv lockFocus];
        NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[cv bounds]];
        [cv unlockFocus];
        NSData *data = [rep TIFFRepresentation];
        [data writeToFile:[[save URL] path] atomically:NO];
```

All I get is a gray image with the correct size. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are using correctly `NSBitmaImageRep`.

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948241/cocoa-how-to-render-view-to-image) for a couple of ways of doing what you are trying to. Possibly the only one that is working for a web view (which is quite a complex beast) is the screenshot+crop approach.

Comment: The screenshot+crop approach works for me, thank you very very much!